# BeautifulSoup4 exclude div that is in wrapper

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I tried to get the all text out of the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="header"><h1>Header</h1></div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="header"><h1>Sub Header</h1></div>
    <p>Target_2</p>
    <p>Target_3</p>
    <p>Target_4</p>
</div>
```

My approach was something like this:

```
targets = soup.find_all("div", class_=["header", "container"])

for html_row in targets:
   for row in html_row.strings:
         print(row)
```

Output:

```
Header
Sub Header
Target_2
Target_3
Target_4
Sub Header
```

My problem is that "Sub Header" is found twice because of the `header` class.
How can I exclude the `header` class inside of the `container` class?
I have to grab everything with the classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the [`recursive`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-recursive-argument) argument to `False`, which will only find direct children:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """
<div class="header"><h1>Header</h1></div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="header"><h1>Sub Header</h1></div>
    <p>Target_2</p>
    <p>Target_3</p>
    <p>Target_4</p>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
targets = soup.find_all("div", class_=["header", "container"], recursive=False)

for tag in targets:
    print(tag.text.strip())
```

Output:

```
Header
Sub Header
Target_2
Target_3
Target_4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put a condition inside the loop to check, if the tag isn't inside other tag with `class="container"` using `.find_parent()`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = '''<div class="header"><h1>Header</h1></div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="header"><h1>Sub Header</h1></div>
    <p>Target_2</p>
    <p>Target_3</p>
    <p>Target_4</p>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
targets = soup.find_all("div", class_=["header", "container"])

for tag in targets:
    if tag.find_parent(attrs={'class':'container'}):
        continue
    print(tag.text.strip())
```

Prints:

```
Header
Sub Header
Target_2
Target_3
Target_4
```